# How many set partitions of [n] are there into exactly two parts, such that the parts have different sizes?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I'm not at all sure how to solve the following question: How many set partitions of [n] are there into exactly two parts, such that the parts have different sizes? Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: If $n$ is odd, every partition is of this form. If $n$ is even, count the number of ways of choosing a subset of size $\frac n2$, subtract that from the total number of partitions.

Comment: Are the partitions $\{(1,2),(3,4,5)\}$ and $\{(3,4,5),(1,2)\}$ counted as one or two? And is the partition $\{(),(1,2,3,4,5)\}$ allowed?

Comment: @user They are counted as 1. And no, by definiton of [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) you need non-empty sets

Comment: @A.Pesare I do not know what kind of partition does OP have in mind. It is not necessary that one which you linked.

Comment: @user: That is the correct definition of *partition*. Any other definition would be non-standard and would require explicit notice.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Are you sure that OP knows standard definition of partition and does not use this word for something else?

Comment: @user: Given the OP’s previous question and acceptance of the answer thereto, yes, I *am* reasonably sure.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have not checked the previous questions of OP before my comment. Will do it next time.

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks so much for your answer, I think I got it now

Comment: Yes, I was referring to set partition as stated in the question